# Port awk one-liner to perl using regexes (Summing groups of data)

Tags: regex, perl, awk

Given the following input:

```
£ cat problem
  Team 7
  John: 19
  Sue: 20
  Pam: 35
  Team 42
  Jeff: 12
  Sam: 3
  Phil: 26
  Jill: 10
  Team 9
  Bill: 19
  John: 7
  Linda: 15
```

I am trying to reproduce the following output in a perl one-liner:

```
£ awk '/Team/ {x=$2} /: *[0-9]+/ {myarray[x]+=$2}; END{for (key in myarray) {print "Team " key ": " myarray[key]}}' problem
Team 42: 51
Team 7: 74
Team 9: 41
```

This (basic) problem and the data actually comes from a perl tutorial.  http://learnperl.scratchcomputing.com/tutorials/csss/

I'm interested in something close to this, which I have tried...literally over 50 variations of:

```
 £ perl -e 'while(<>){if (/Team/){$x = /(\d+)/;}else{/(\d+)/;$myarray{$x}+= {$1}; }} foreach $key (keys %myarray){print "$key\n";}' problem
```

I know that 1) these regexes are not returning the match (the `+= {$1}` was an attempt to remedy that), and 2) even if they were I am probably populating the hash incorrectly.  Googling potential solutions returns me verbose, multiline code.  I was waiting to get the keys outputting correctly before I even bothered moving onto the values, btw.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without examining the awk code, I'd write this perl:

```
perl -lne '
        if (/Team (\d+)/) {
            $t = $1;
        } elsif (/: (\d+)/) {
            $score{$t} += $1
        }
    } END {
        printf "Team %d: %d\n", $_, $score{$_} for keys %score
' problem
```

```
Team 7: 74
Team 9: 41
Team 42: 51
```

The `-n` option implicitly wraps a `while (<>) {...}` loop around the given code. See `perldoc perlrun` for all the details.

The `} END {` bit exploits that, and allows you to collect data inside the while loop, then do stuff with it when the loop is complete.

---

You can see how perl deals with one-liners by adding the `-MO=Deparse` option:

```
perl -MO=Deparse -lne '
        if (/Team (\d+)/) {
            $t = $1;
        } elsif (/: (\d+)/) {
            $score{$t} += $1
        }
    } END {
        printf "Team %d: %d\n", $_, $score{$_} for keys %score
' problem
```

```
BEGIN { $/ = "\n"; $\ = "\n"; }
LINE: while (defined($_ = <ARGV>)) {
    chomp $_;
    if (/Team (\d+)/) {
        $t = $1;
    }
    elsif (/: (\d+)/) {
        $score{$t} += $1;
    }
}
sub END {
    printf "Team %d: %d\n", $_, $score{$_} foreach (keys %score);
}
-e syntax OK
```

I'm not sure why it turns the END block into a subroutine though.

---

A couple of notes about your code:

1. Use better variable names.
2. `$x = /(\d+)/`

   - `m//` used in scalar context will return a true/false value, regardless of the use of capturing parentheses (ref: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators)
   - to assign the captured text to variables, you must have a list context on the left-hand side: `($a, $list, $of, $variables) = (a, list, of, values)`, so

     ```
     ($x) = /(\d+)/;   # with parentheses on the left-hand side
     ```
3. `$myarray{$x}+= {$1}`

   - when you use `{...}` as an expression, you are creating a **hash reference**
   - in this case `{$1}`, your hash does not have enough elements: it requires an even numbered list of key-value pairs.
   - you just want `$myarray{$x} += $1`
4. `foreach $key (keys %myarray){...}`

   - an alternate way to iterate over a hash is to use the `each` function in a while loop:

     ```
     while (my ($key, $value) = each %myarray) {
         print "Team $key: $value\n";
     }
     ```

Comment: I knew about `-n` but did not know perl supported END, which is why I broke it out :)  Thank you, this clarifies quite a few things for me.

Comment: #1: I have an obsession with writing filthy perl, and I need to stop.  Sorry.  #2, #3, and #4:  Wow, thank you for the great feedback.  If you care, I'll put a bounty on this when it's eligible because I learned so much from this answer.

Comment: @zzxyz Note that even this works: `perl -nE'$sum += $. }{ say $sum' file` -- you may write `}{` alone. But sticking that `END` is much nicer, which is why glenn wrote it that way. I never knew that it makes `END` a sub!

Comment: @zdim: `perlmod` has this *"These code blocks can be prefixed with sub to give the appearance of a subroutine (although this is not considered good style)"*. I guess `B::Deparse` writes poor code!

Comment: @Borodin Ah! Ah!  (It crossed my mind that it may be "just so" but then ...)  This is excellent! :)

Comment: @glenn: *"when you say `$x = (a, list, of, values)`, then `$x` contains the* ***number*** *of values"* When you assign a comma-separated list in scalar context like that, `$x` is set to the *last element* of the list, because it is is the last expression to be evaluated. `m//` in scalar context returns a boolean value according to whether the match succeeded, and is unaffected by the number of captures.